# How are the directories of a Django Project tree referred to?

Tags: django

Assume you have a directory where you keep all your Django projects:

```
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects
```

If you in this directory call

```
django-admin startproject blog
```

you'll end up with the following director tree:

```
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects/blog
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects/blog/blog
```

What's the first `blog` and whats `blog/blog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the command:

```
django-admin startproject blog
```

The first `blog` is just a website folder or simply a container for your project. The `blog` subfolder is the actual project folder which contains the following:

```
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects/blog/blog/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

Bottom line is, the first blog is simply a container of your django project/files. You can always change its filename and it won't affect anything Django-related.

Also, what you can do is make use of:

```
django-admin startproject blog .
```

Notice the `.` after the name of your project, this will allow you to create a project directly in the current directory without having `blog/blog`

So, if you do:

```
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects> mkdir first_django_project
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects> cd first_django_project
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects> django-admin startproject blog .
```

What you'll get is this project tree:

```
$HOME/Programming/Django_Projects/first_django_project/
    blog/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
```

Therefore no duplicate/confusing names.

Comment: Great pointing out about the terminal `.` Really confusing by default IMHO